# Ionic Capacitor in Xcode Error - [warn] Native: tried calling StatusBar.overlaysWebView, but the StatusBar plugin is not installed

Tags: angular, xcode8, capacitor, ionic5

Am using ionic angular application. I created mobile app using ionic with capacitor.
I added status bar in my application using below steps.

Install Statusbar

```
npm install cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install @ionic-native/status-bar
ionic cap sync
```

Code in app.component.ts

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
constructor(private statusBar: StatusBar) { }

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#f8d047');
});
```

When i run my application in Xcode below error occur.

[warn] - Native: tried calling StatusBar.overlaysWebView, but the StatusBar plugin is not installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cordova-plugin-statusbar` is not compatible with Capacitor, when you run the `sync` command you should see a message telling you that

Comment: Is there any other way to add status bar in ionic/capacitor project?

Comment: Capacitor has a Statusbar plugin, but overlay function is not available for iOS, iOS always overlays the status bar